# How to make smooth vision of navmesh agent moves?

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, repository, navmesh

Im using Unity 2d with NavMeshPlus (git repository which creates ability to use NavMesh in 2D, [there](https://github.com/h8man/NavMeshPlus))
When i move my character with following him camera and navmesh agent coming to me, his moves seems rough. It happens when my camera moving in opposite direction.

Enemy code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (agent.isOnNavMesh && Vector3.Distance(Player.transform.position, agent.destination) > 0.1f) {
    agent.CalculatePath(Player.transform.position, path);
    agent.SetPath(path);
}
    Vector3 position = transform.position;
    position.z = 0f;
    transform.position = position;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
}
```

Camera script:

```
    void FixedUpdate() {
    Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(Player.transform.position.x, Player.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, ref velocity, smoothTime);
}
```

Here is a video: [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15knCb7RNxn0_iiy2LyirGsHlVCUNaPO4/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: Do you really need to set the path every frame? From memory ive only used set destination.

Comment: It doesnt really matter, nothing changes if i replace setpath with setdestination